# SQL XML Import: XQuery [value()]: ")" was expected

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery

I am trying to insert data into a table in SQL from XML data. The XML file was created from Microsoft Excel, which gives it this header:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

I am using this query to parse it:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' as ss)

select X.value('(ss:Row/ss:Cell/ss:@Data)','varchar(max)')
from @allUsers.nodes('Workbook/Worksheet/Table') as T(X)
```

which parses for about a half a second and then gives me this error:

> XQuery [value()]: ")" was expected.

The data within the XML being parsed contain phone numbers, some of which contain `(` and `)` e.g.:

```
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="30">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">JohnSmith</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">JohnSmith</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">XYZ</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">(555) 555-5555</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22"/>
   </Row>
```

but I don't think that an open parentheses within the  would cause a problem.

My question is, has anybody else encountered this error before, since I can't seem to find any help through an online search?

**EDIT**
I think I may have been going in the wrong direction in this case. I have posted a new question here:
[Separating XML values with the same tags into different rows SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244202/separating-xml-values-with-the-same-tags-into-different-rows-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked very similar questions. I took the information from both and built this working example. Be aware of the xmlns-namespace which must be declared as "DEFAULT":

Simplified your XML, but the idea should be OK...

```
DECLARE @allUsers XML=
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Worksheet>
 <Table>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="30">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">Jane Doe</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">JaneDoe</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">XYZ</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">(555) 555-5555</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22"/>
   </Row>
   </Table>
 </Worksheet>   
</Workbook>';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' as ss
                     ,DEFAULT 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet')
SELECT T.X.value('Cell[1]/Data[1]','varchar(max)') AS DontKnow1
      ,T.X.value('Cell[2]/Data[1]','varchar(max)') AS Name
      ,T.X.value('Cell[3]/Data[1]','varchar(max)') AS UserName
      ,T.X.value('Cell[4]/Data[1]','varchar(max)') AS DontKnow2
      ,T.X.value('Cell[5]/Data[1]','varchar(max)') AS Telephone
      ,T.X.value('Cell[6]/Data[1]','varchar(max)') AS DontKnow3
FROM @allUsers.nodes('/Workbook/Worksheet/Table/Row') as T(X)
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to read that I could help you... Would be nice to vote up, thx!

Comment: I actually think that the other question has more accurate title and description of the problem and will be more useful for others in the future. Would you mind changing your answer to there to this one? I am going to include the header information from here

Comment: I will copy this to a second answer in your other question. It's up to you to decide which one you want to vote and accept. Is this OK?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the parenthesis in the phone number that causes the error, but your XQuery query, which I think has a syntax error.

The @ is not at the proper location, and may also need to go since Data is not an attribute but an element. You could try to change

```
select X.value('(ss:Row/ss:Cell/ss:@Data)','varchar(max)')
from @allUsers.nodes('Workbook/Worksheet/Table') as T(X)
```

to

```
select X.value('(ss:Row/ss:Cell/ss:Data)[1]','varchar(max)')
from @allUsers.nodes('ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table') as T(X)
```

Comment: Also, as far as I understand it from the documentation, value() should only return one value at a time, which means you may need to either push some more of the XPath into the "from" part, or to add a [1] at the end of your XQuery to take only the first value, etc.

Comment: doing that gives me an empty data set. I made some changes and I am going to ask a new question and link it here.

Comment: The "ss"-namespace is not bound to "Row" or "Cell" this is default namespace "xmlns" which must be declared with XMLNAMESPACES as default namespace...

Comment: Actually the prefix used (or absence thereof) should not be relevant, as QNames are compared only in terms of namespaces and local names, the prefix being only a proxy to the namespace -- unless of course SQL Server has different semantics, which would surprise me. However, your answer does address the issue of returning each value independently, iterating on rows, and I think this is what makes it great.

Comment: Looking at the original query, "Workbook/Worksheet/Table" does not have the ss prefix and since there is no default namespace declared either, they don't match against the document. This is why nothing is returned. Good (double-)catch Schnugo! I'm upvoting your answer.